# Table for Fund Management

Tags: html, xcode

Can someone help me with my code in html?
My problem is about the search button. I can search but I can't get the result I wanted. I want the data that is being search to be highlighted only but with my code, it will ruin the table, instead of just being highlighted, the data that has been search is going to the side and it ruins the table.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 

<head> 
    <title> 
        Trust Fund 
    </title> 
    <style> 
        body { 
            margin: 4rem; 
        } 

        #formContainer { 
            margin-bottom: 20px; 
        } 

        label { 
            display: block; 
            margin-top: 10px; 
        } 

        input, 
        textarea { 
            width: 600px; 
            padding: 10px; 
            margin-top: 5px; 
            border: 1px solid #ccc; 
            border-radius: 4px; 
        } 

        button { 
            margin: 10px; 
            padding: 8px 16px; 
            background-color: #45b6fe; 
            color: #fff; 
            border: none; 
            border-radius: 4px; 
            cursor: pointer; 
        } 

        button:hover { 
            background-color: #45a049; 
        } 

        table { 
            border-collapse: collapse; 
            margin-bottom: 20px; 
            width: 50%; 
        } 

        th, 
        td { 
            border: 1px solid #ddd; 
            padding: 8px; 
            text-align: left; 
        } 

        th { 
            background-color: #4CAF50; 
            color: #fff; 
        } 
    </style> 
</head> 

<body> 
    <h1 style="color: black;"> 
        Fund Cluster 
    </h1> 
    <h2>Month of July</h2> 

    <div id="formContainer"> 
        <label for="dvInput"> 
            DV #: 
        </label> 
        <input type="text"
            id="dvInput"
            placeholder="Enter DV #"> 
        <label for="dateInput"> 
            DV Date: 
        </label> 
        <input type="email"
            id="dateInput"
            placeholder="Enter dv date"> 
        <label for="numberInput"> 
            Check No.: 
        </label> 
        <input type="text"
            id="numberInput"
            placeholder="Enter Check No."> 
        <label for="checkInput"> 
                    Check Date: 
        </label> 
        <input type="text"
            id="checkInput"
            placeholder="Enter Check Date"> 
        <label for="payeeInput">            
                    Payee: 
        </label> 
        <input type="text"
            id="payeeInput"
            placeholder="Enter  Payee"> 
        <label for="uacsInput"> 
                    UACS Code: 
        </label> 
        <input type="text"
            id="uacsInput"
            placeholder="Enter UACS Code"> 
        <label for="particularsInput">
                    Particulars: 
        </label> 
        <input type="text"
            id="particularsInput"
            placeholder="Enter Particulars"> 
            <label for="projectInput">
                    Project: 
        </label> 
        <input type="text"
            id="projectInput"
            placeholder="Enter Project"> 
        <label for="periodInput">
                    Period: 
        </label> 
        <input type="text"
            id="periodInput"
            placeholder="Enter Period"> 
        <label for="grossInput">
            Gross: 
        </label> 
        <input type="text"
            id="grossInput"
            placeholder="Enter Gross">
        <label for="birInput">
            BIR:
        </label> 
        <input type="text"
            id="birInput"
            placeholder="Enter BIR"> 
        <label for="netInput">
            Net: 
        </label> 
        <input type="text"
            id="netInput"
            placeholder="Enter Net"> 
        <label for="receiptsInput">
            Receipts: 
        </label> 
        <input type="text"
            id="receiptsInput"
            placeholder="Enter Receipts"> 
        <label for="totalInput">
            BCA Total/Balance: 
        </label> 
        <input type="text"
              id="totalInput"
                placeholder="Enter BCA Total/Balance"> 
        </textarea> 
        <button onclick="addData()"> 
            Add 
        </button> 
    </div> 
     <div class="search-bar">
        <input type="text" id="searchInput" placeholder="Search">
        <button onclick="searchData()">Search</button>
    </div>
    <table id="outputTable"> 
        <tr>
      <th rowspan="2">DV #</th>
      <th rowspan="2">DV Date</th>
      <th rowspan="2">Check No.</th>
      <th rowspan="2">Check Date</th>
      <th rowspan="2">Payee</th>
      <th rowspan="2">UACS Code</th>
      <th rowspan="2">Particulars</th>
      <th rowspan="2">Project</th>
      <th rowspan="2">Period</th>
      <th colspan="3">Disbursement</th>
      <th rowspan="2">Receipts</th>
      <th rowspan="2">BCA Total/Balance</th>
      <th rowspan="2">Action</th> 
      
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
      <th>Gross</th>
      <th>BIR</th>
      <th>Net</th>
    </tr>
    </table> 
    <script> 
        function addData() { 
            // Get input values 
            let dv = 
                document.getElementById("dvInput").value; 
            let date = 
                document.getElementById("dateInput").value; 
            let number = 
                document.getElementById("numberInput").value; 
            let check = 
                document.getElementById("checkInput").value; 
            let payee = 
                document.getElementById("payeeInput").value; 
            let uacs = 
                document.getElementById("uacsInput").value; 
            let particulars = 
                document.getElementById("particularsInput").value; 
            let project = 
                document.getElementById("projectInput").value; 
            let period = 
                document.getElementById("periodInput").value;
            let gross = 
                document.getElementById("grossInput").value; 
            let bir = 
                document.getElementById("birInput").value;
            let net = 
                document.getElementById("netInput").value;
            let receipts = 
                document.getElementById("receiptsInput").value; 
            let total = 
                 document.getElementById("totalInput").value; 
            
            
            // Get the table and insert a new row at the end 
            let table = document.getElementById("outputTable"); 
            let newRow = table.insertRow(table.rows.length); 
            
            // Insert data into cells of the new row 
            newRow.insertCell(0).innerHTML = dv; 
            newRow.insertCell(1).innerHTML = date; 
            newRow.insertCell(2).innerHTML = number; 
            newRow.insertCell(3).innerHTML = check; 
            newRow.insertCell(4).innerHTML = payee; 
            newRow.insertCell(5).innerHTML = uacs; 
            newRow.insertCell(6).innerHTML = particulars; 
            newRow.insertCell(7).innerHTML = project; 
            newRow.insertCell(8).innerHTML = period; 
            newRow.insertCell(9).innerHTML = gross;
            newRow.insertCell(10).innerHTML = bir;
            newRow.insertCell(11).innerHTML = net;
            newRow.insertCell(12).innerHTML = receipts; 
            newRow.insertCell(13).innerHTML = total;
            newRow.insertCell(14).innerHTML = 
                '<button onclick="editData(this)">Edit</button>'+ 
                '<button onclick="deleteData(this)">Delete</button>'; 
            
            // Clear input fields 
            clearInputs(); 
        } 

        function editData(button) { 
            
            // Get the parent row of the clicked button 
            let row = button.parentNode.parentNode; 
            
            // Get the cells within the row 
            let dvCell = row.cells[0]; 
            let dateCell = row.cells[1]; 
            let numberCell = row.cells[2]; 
            let checkCell = row.cells[3];
            let payeeCell = row.cells[4]; 
            let uacsCell = row.cells[5]; 
            let particularsCell = row.cells[6]; 
            let projectCell = row.cells[7]; 
            let periodCell = row.cells[8];
            let grossCell = row.cells[9];
            let birCell = row.cells[10]; 
            let netCell = row.cells[11];     
            let receiptsCell = row.cells[12]; 
            let totalCell = row.cells[13];
            
            // Prompt the user to enter updated values 
            let dvInput = 
                prompt("Enter the updated dv:", 
                    dvCell.innerHTML); 
            let dateInput = 
                prompt("Enter the updated date:", 
                    dateCell.innerHTML); 
            let numberInput = 
                prompt("Enter the updated number:", 
                    numberCell.innerHTML); 
            let checkInput = 
                prompt("Enter the updated check:", 
                    checkCell.innerHTML); 
            let payeeInput = 
                prompt("Enter the updated payee:", 
                    payeeCell.innerHTML); 
            let uacsInput = 
                prompt("Enter the updated UACS:", 
                    uacsCell.innerHTML); 
            let particularsInput = 
                prompt("Enter the updated particulars:", 
                    particularsCell.innerHTML); 
            let projectInput = 
                prompt("Enter the updated project:", 
                projectCell.innerHTML);
            let periodInput = 
                prompt("Enter the updated period:", 
                    periodCell.innerHTML); 
            let grossInput = 
                prompt("Enter the updated Gross:", 
                grossCell.innerHTML); 
            let birInput = 
                prompt("Enter the updated BIR:", 
                birCell.innerHTML); 
            let netInput = 
                prompt("Enter the updated Net:", 
                netCell.innerHTML); 
            let receiptsInput = 
                prompt("Enter the updated receipts:", 
                receiptsCell.innerHTML);
            let totalInput = 
                prompt("Enter the updated total:", 
                totalCell.innerHTML);  

            // Update the cell contents with the new values 
            dvCell.innerHTML = dvInput; 
            dateCell.innerHTML = dateInput; 
            numberCell.innerHTML = numberInput; 
            checkCell.innerHTML = checkInput;
            payeeCell.innerHTML = payeeInput; 
            uacsCell.innerHTML = uacsInput; 
            particularsCell.innerHTML = particularsInput; 
            projectCell.innerHTML = projectInput;  
            periodCell.innerHTML = periodInput; 
            grossCell.innerHTML = grossInput; 
            birCell.innerHTML = birInput; 
            netCell.innerHTML = netInput; 
            receiptsCell.innerHTML = receiptsInput;  
            totalCell.innerHTML = totalInput; 
        } 
        function deleteData(button) { 
            
            // Get the parent row of the clicked button 
            let row = button.parentNode.parentNode; 

            // Remove the row from the table 
            row.parentNode.removeChild(row); 
        } 
        function clearInputs() { 
            
            // Clear input fields 
            document.getElementById("dvInput").value = ""; 
            document.getElementById("dateInput").value = ""; 
            document.getElementById("numberInput").value = ""; 
            document.getElementById("checkInput").value = ""; 
            document.getElementById("payeeInput").value = ""; 
            document.getElementById("uacsInput").value = ""; 
            document.getElementById("particularsInput").value = ""; 
            document.getElementById("projectInput").value = "";
            document.getElementById("periodInput").value = "";
            document.getElementById("grossInput").value = ""; 
            document.getElementById("birInput").value = ""; 
            document.getElementById("netInput").value = ""; 
            document.getElementById("receiptsInput").value = ""; 
            document.getElementById("totalInput").value = "";
        }
           function searchData() {
    let input = document.getElementById("searchInput").value.toLowerCase();
    let table = document.getElementById("outputTable");

    for (let i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
        let row = table.rows[i];
        let found = false;

        for (let j = 0; j < row.cells.length; j++) {
            let cellValue = row.cells[j].innerHTML.toLowerCase();
            if (cellValue.includes(input)) {
                found = true;
                row.cells[j].style.backgroundColor = "yellow"; // Highlight the cell
            } else {
                row.cells[j].style.backgroundColor = ""; // Remove highlight from other cells
            }
        }

        if (found) {
            row.style.display = "";
        } else {
            row.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
     
}
    </script> 
    
</body> 
</html>




type here
```

[this is the result after adding a data and when I'm going to search the data, the data should only be highlighted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFYMU.png)

[but then when i tried searching a specific data, it goes like this and it ruins the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2D8W.png)

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue for you and highlighted search matched text with color instead of background color

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 

<head> 
    <title> 
        Trust Fund 
    </title> 
    <style> 
        body { 
            margin: 4rem; 
        } 

        #formContainer { 
            margin-bottom: 20px; 
        } 

        label { 
            display: block; 
            margin-top: 10px; 
        } 

        input, 
        textarea { 
            width: 600px; 
            padding: 10px; 
            margin-top: 5px; 
            border: 1px solid #ccc; 
            border-radius: 4px; 
        } 

        button { 
            margin: 10px; 
            padding: 8px 16px; 
            background-color: #45b6fe; 
            color: #fff; 
            border: none; 
            border-radius: 4px; 
            cursor: pointer; 
        } 

        button:hover { 
            background-color: #45a049; 
        } 

        table { 
            border-collapse: collapse; 
            margin-bottom: 20px; 
            width: 50%; 
        } 

        th, 
        td { 
            border: 1px solid #ddd; 
            padding: 8px; 
            text-align: left; 
        } 

        th { 
            background-color: #4CAF50; 
            color: #fff; 
        } 
    </style> 
</head> 

<body> 
    <h1 style="color: black;"> 
        Fund Cluster 
    </h1> 
    <h2>Month of July</h2> 

    <div id="formContainer"> 
        <label for="dvInput"> 
            DV #: 
        </label> 
        <input type="text"
            id="dvInput"
            placeholder="Enter DV #"> 
        <label for="dateInput"> 
            DV Date: 
        </label> 
        <input type="email"
            id="dateInput"
            placeholder="Enter dv date"> 
        <label for="numberInput"> 
            Check No.: 
        </label> 
        <input type="text"
            id="numberInput"
            placeholder="Enter Check No."> 
        <label for="checkInput"> 
                    Check Date: 
        </label> 
        <input type="text"
            id="checkInput"
            placeholder="Enter Check Date"> 
        <label for="payeeInput">            
                    Payee: 
        </label> 
        <input type="text"
            id="payeeInput"
            placeholder="Enter  Payee"> 
        <label for="uacsInput"> 
                    UACS Code: 
        </label> 
        <input type="text"
            id="uacsInput"
            placeholder="Enter UACS Code"> 
        <label for="particularsInput">
                    Particulars: 
        </label> 
        <input type="text"
            id="particularsInput"
            placeholder="Enter Particulars"> 
            <label for="projectInput">
                    Project: 
        </label> 
        <input type="text"
            id="projectInput"
            placeholder="Enter Project"> 
        <label for="periodInput">
                    Period: 
        </label> 
        <input type="text"
            id="periodInput"
            placeholder="Enter Period"> 
        <label for="grossInput">
            Gross: 
        </label> 
        <input type="text"
            id="grossInput"
            placeholder="Enter Gross">
        <label for="birInput">
            BIR:
        </label> 
        <input type="text"
            id="birInput"
            placeholder="Enter BIR"> 
        <label for="netInput">
            Net: 
        </label> 
        <input type="text"
            id="netInput"
            placeholder="Enter Net"> 
        <label for="receiptsInput">
            Receipts: 
        </label> 
        <input type="text"
            id="receiptsInput"
            placeholder="Enter Receipts"> 
        <label for="totalInput">
            BCA Total/Balance: 
        </label> 
        <input type="text"
              id="totalInput"
                placeholder="Enter BCA Total/Balance"> 
        </textarea> 
        <button onclick="addData()"> 
            Add 
        </button> 
    </div> 
     <div class="search-bar">
        <input type="text" id="searchInput" placeholder="Search">
        <button onclick="searchData()">Search</button>
    </div>
    <table id="outputTable"> 
        <tr>
      <th rowspan="2">DV #</th>
      <th rowspan="2">DV Date</th>
      <th rowspan="2">Check No.</th>
      <th rowspan="2">Check Date</th>
      <th rowspan="2">Payee</th>
      <th rowspan="2">UACS Code</th>
      <th rowspan="2">Particulars</th>
      <th rowspan="2">Project</th>
      <th rowspan="2">Period</th>
      <th colspan="3">Disbursement</th>
      <th rowspan="2">Receipts</th>
      <th rowspan="2">BCA Total/Balance</th>
      <th rowspan="2">Action</th> 
      
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
      <th>Gross</th>
      <th>BIR</th>
      <th>Net</th>
    </tr>
    </table> 
    <script> 
        function addData() { 
            // Get input values 
            let dv = 
                document.getElementById("dvInput").value; 
            let date = 
                document.getElementById("dateInput").value; 
            let number = 
                document.getElementById("numberInput").value; 
            let check = 
                document.getElementById("checkInput").value; 
            let payee = 
                document.getElementById("payeeInput").value; 
            let uacs = 
                document.getElementById("uacsInput").value; 
            let particulars = 
                document.getElementById("particularsInput").value; 
            let project = 
                document.getElementById("projectInput").value; 
            let period = 
                document.getElementById("periodInput").value;
            let gross = 
                document.getElementById("grossInput").value; 
            let bir = 
                document.getElementById("birInput").value;
            let net = 
                document.getElementById("netInput").value;
            let receipts = 
                document.getElementById("receiptsInput").value; 
            let total = 
                 document.getElementById("totalInput").value; 
            
            
            // Get the table and insert a new row at the end 
            let table = document.getElementById("outputTable"); 
            let newRow = table.insertRow(table.rows.length); 
            
            // Insert data into cells of the new row 
            newRow.insertCell(0).innerHTML = dv; 
            newRow.insertCell(1).innerHTML = date; 
            newRow.insertCell(2).innerHTML = number; 
            newRow.insertCell(3).innerHTML = check; 
            newRow.insertCell(4).innerHTML = payee; 
            newRow.insertCell(5).innerHTML = uacs; 
            newRow.insertCell(6).innerHTML = particulars; 
            newRow.insertCell(7).innerHTML = project; 
            newRow.insertCell(8).innerHTML = period; 
            newRow.insertCell(9).innerHTML = gross;
            newRow.insertCell(10).innerHTML = bir;
            newRow.insertCell(11).innerHTML = net;
            newRow.insertCell(12).innerHTML = receipts; 
            newRow.insertCell(13).innerHTML = total;
            newRow.insertCell(14).innerHTML = 
                '<button onclick="editData(this)">Edit</button>'+ 
                '<button onclick="deleteData(this)">Delete</button>'; 
            
            // Clear input fields 
            clearInputs(); 
        } 

        function editData(button) { 
            
            // Get the parent row of the clicked button 
            let row = button.parentNode.parentNode; 
            
            // Get the cells within the row 
            let dvCell = row.cells[0]; 
            let dateCell = row.cells[1]; 
            let numberCell = row.cells[2]; 
            let checkCell = row.cells[3];
            let payeeCell = row.cells[4]; 
            let uacsCell = row.cells[5]; 
            let particularsCell = row.cells[6]; 
            let projectCell = row.cells[7]; 
            let periodCell = row.cells[8];
            let grossCell = row.cells[9];
            let birCell = row.cells[10]; 
            let netCell = row.cells[11];     
            let receiptsCell = row.cells[12]; 
            let totalCell = row.cells[13];
            
            // Prompt the user to enter updated values 
            let dvInput = 
                prompt("Enter the updated dv:", 
                    dvCell.innerHTML); 
            let dateInput = 
                prompt("Enter the updated date:", 
                    dateCell.innerHTML); 
            let numberInput = 
                prompt("Enter the updated number:", 
                    numberCell.innerHTML); 
            let checkInput = 
                prompt("Enter the updated check:", 
                    checkCell.innerHTML); 
            let payeeInput = 
                prompt("Enter the updated payee:", 
                    payeeCell.innerHTML); 
            let uacsInput = 
                prompt("Enter the updated UACS:", 
                    uacsCell.innerHTML); 
            let particularsInput = 
                prompt("Enter the updated particulars:", 
                    particularsCell.innerHTML); 
            let projectInput = 
                prompt("Enter the updated project:", 
                projectCell.innerHTML);
            let periodInput = 
                prompt("Enter the updated period:", 
                    periodCell.innerHTML); 
            let grossInput = 
                prompt("Enter the updated Gross:", 
                grossCell.innerHTML); 
            let birInput = 
                prompt("Enter the updated BIR:", 
                birCell.innerHTML); 
            let netInput = 
                prompt("Enter the updated Net:", 
                netCell.innerHTML); 
            let receiptsInput = 
                prompt("Enter the updated receipts:", 
                receiptsCell.innerHTML);
            let totalInput = 
                prompt("Enter the updated total:", 
                totalCell.innerHTML);  

            // Update the cell contents with the new values 
            dvCell.innerHTML = dvInput; 
            dateCell.innerHTML = dateInput; 
            numberCell.innerHTML = numberInput; 
            checkCell.innerHTML = checkInput;
            payeeCell.innerHTML = payeeInput; 
            uacsCell.innerHTML = uacsInput; 
            particularsCell.innerHTML = particularsInput; 
            projectCell.innerHTML = projectInput;  
            periodCell.innerHTML = periodInput; 
            grossCell.innerHTML = grossInput; 
            birCell.innerHTML = birInput; 
            netCell.innerHTML = netInput; 
            receiptsCell.innerHTML = receiptsInput;  
            totalCell.innerHTML = totalInput; 
        } 
        function deleteData(button) { 
            
            // Get the parent row of the clicked button 
            let row = button.parentNode.parentNode; 

            // Remove the row from the table 
            row.parentNode.removeChild(row); 
        } 
        function clearInputs() { 
            
            // Clear input fields 
            document.getElementById("dvInput").value = ""; 
            document.getElementById("dateInput").value = ""; 
            document.getElementById("numberInput").value = ""; 
            document.getElementById("checkInput").value = ""; 
            document.getElementById("payeeInput").value = ""; 
            document.getElementById("uacsInput").value = ""; 
            document.getElementById("particularsInput").value = ""; 
            document.getElementById("projectInput").value = "";
            document.getElementById("periodInput").value = "";
            document.getElementById("grossInput").value = ""; 
            document.getElementById("birInput").value = ""; 
            document.getElementById("netInput").value = ""; 
            document.getElementById("receiptsInput").value = ""; 
            document.getElementById("totalInput").value = "";
        }
           function searchData() {
    let input = document.getElementById("searchInput").value.toLowerCase();
    let table = document.getElementById("outputTable");

    if(input.length>0){
        for (let i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
        let row = table.rows[i];
        let found = false;

   for(let j=0;j< row.children.length;j++){
    if(row.children[j].textContent.toLowerCase().includes(input)){
        row.children[j].style.color="#d62d55";
        found=true;
       
       
    }else{
        if(row.children[j].tagName=="td"){
            row.children[j].style.color="black";
        }
    }
   } 
    }
}
    
}
    </script> 
    
</body> 
</html>
```

have a look hope it will help you